# How to change the colours of a contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this code below to create a contour plot, and it is okay, very succeed, but I cannot change the colors, do someone knows how to do that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
N = 500 #number of points for plotting/interpolation
x, y, z = np.genfromtxt(r'data.txt', unpack=True)
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(),N)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(),N)
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]),method='cubic')
fig = plt.figure()
pcolor(xi, yi, zi)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.colorbar()
cmap=matplotlib.colors.Colormap('hot')
plt.show()
```

This code is creating something like this [Output Image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-yFOhP_HdZIg/UMChMvRCsdI/AAAAAAAAAes/xvrs2HQRDSg/s1600/labeled_contours.jpg)
In that scale, but I would like to have something like this [Expexted Image](http://theses.ulaval.ca/archimede/fichiers/23666/23666_53.png):

I mean, I just want to change the colours, the images came from google, I just want s
imilar colours...

Thank you

Comment: Check this link: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps

Comment: FYI..for multiple lines of code you can always use `indentation of 4 spaces`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pcolor(xi, yi, zi, cmap=plt.get_cmap('hot'))
```

get the names for the standard colormaps from
[here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps)